# D2L Valance: PUT of grades with Java

Tags: java, desire2learn

I was curious as to whether anyone has successfully implemented in Java the route in D2L using Valance as follows:

PUT /d2l/api/le/(D2LVERSION: version)/(D2LID: orgUnitId)/grades/(D2LID: gradeObjectId)/values/(D2LID: userId)

I have been struggling with receiving a 404 from this call when I have checked thoroughly that the required IDs match my records in D2L. When I log into D2L with the Instructor level account that I am using in Java I see that the Course, Test, and Participants are there. The IDs for these are used in the Java code to call the above route, but I receive a 404 and a grade is not updated.

Here is a snip of the code:

```
HttpURLConnection  connection = null ;

    try {
        uri = userContext.createAuthenticatedUri ("/d2l/api/le/1.0/"+courseId+"/grades/"+gradeId+"/values/"+ userId, "PUT");

        connection= (HttpURLConnection)uri.toURL().openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestMethod("PUT");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

        OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
        String updatedScore = "{\"GradeObjectType\":1,\"PointsNumerator\":\"5\"}";
        os.write(updatedScore.getBytes());
        os.flush();

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The courseID, gradeID, and userID are being passed in and have been verified in the D2L Web UI.
As you can see, I have a JSON string being created for a GradeObjectType of 1 and a PointsNumerator of 5. Are there special permissions that this Instructor account must have beyond the default Instructor account permissions to permit such a call?

Any thoughts would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. (If you haven't already) You could try making get calls to retrieve these values to ensure they are present and your basic logic is working.
2. If you have access to a very priveleged account you could use that account to try to rule out permissions problems. Instructors that can set grades in the UI *should* be able to set grades via the API.

*update:*

An example of a successful request and response follows, perhaps you can identify differences:

```
REQUEST:

PUT https://valence.desire2learn.com/d2l/api/le/1.0/7574/grades/4852/values/3902?x_b=xDaPHeptaw9syoI1EGdeJ1&x_a=L2Hd9WvDTcyiyu5n2AEgpg&x_d=6U5NTYnTswz4gnu-vZHT3bajswsp3jvxYtwzoeOWKUs&x_c=a6f5hEMrvAxC6PS5UlSUOusVpj-XKnOBwxqhYg5pNtg&x_t=1343070852 HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: application/json

{
                "GradeObjectType": 1,
                "PointsNumerator": 9
}


RESPONSE:

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 0
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
Date: Mon, 23 Jul 2012 19:14:48 GMT
```

Comment: Yes..tried the with/without quotes with no difference. I was just working on a GET routine as you suggested, so that should reveal something. Do the parameters courseId, gradeId, and userId in the path shown above need to be quoted or follow a parameter style? Thanks for a quick reply.

Comment: No, those parameters appear in the route just as integers. For a grade retrieval the example of a working retrieval (time has expired so won't work for you):  GET https://valence.desire2learn.com/d2l/api/le/1.0/6784/grades/2950/values/3670?x_b=1JEx5tX6td9EUbaLGp9vBR&x_a=L2Hd9WvDTcyiyu5n2AEgpg&x_d=auGXdU44ojlQiVko-MSRcP259njaZlaqOlWqwThj-b4&x_c=70o8dipwxUvp_EEBMBCnZjIs2yqvC0jPGj-bvfFwMe4&x_t=1337292473 HTTP/1.1

Comment: So I seem to be breaking on a particular user for a given grade object. They show up in the Web UI, but when doing a GET /d2l/api/le/1.0/{courseId}/grades/{gradeId}/values/{userId} I get a not found. This is also after entering grades for that user in the Web UI as well. So its simply not seeing it.

Comment: Are other users and grade objects working? If so then I would look for differences in the roll used for this user or the properties of this grade object (basically narrowing down differences). If you are only seeing it situational to this user or item it sounds config like, if nothing is working for you it sounds like something is wrong with how the request is being prepared. Instead of code, could you add a "how does it look on the wire" type trace for easier comparison.

Comment: As it turns out the 404 errors were a side-effect of a permissions issue setting in the instance that we were hitting regarding the update of grades for the particular user role that we were using. In addition a downstream error of 400 led us to attempting to update a grade with a value (say 50) when max points is set to 0. This is possible when an instructor can potentially allow for extra credit for an assignment. The assignment must be set to allow for a grade to exceed the max points before the 400 would go away. The source example above works, but with the grade <= max points.